# Scheduled Managed Data Refresh does not work

Tags: 2013, data, powerpivot, data-refresh

I have a situation where Manage PowerPivot Data Refresh feature has suddenly stopped on Site collection. I can see the Data Refresh History which shows all the previous daily automatic data refresh has been successful.

The Reporting service account has read permission on the external database.
The excel file on the SharePoint is configured with external database connection string. I have checked the Default Powerpivot service application and Excel Services application status are Online. And if i click 'Refresh all Data' from Excel file it updates the data but does not get saved. The test environment does not have any issue with same setup. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is now fixed. I ran every PowerShell command to check using [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/install-windows/checklist-use-powershell-to-verify-power-pivot-for-sharepoint#bkmk_powerpivot_service_application), I found from Event log that one of the file was frequently failing because of unsupported format.

After I deleted it, all the other files with scheduled data were successfully getting refreshed.

Hope this helps someone facing the similar issue.

```
07/12/2017 08:50:55.77  w3wp.exe (0x0C24)                           0x90A4  PowerPivot Service              Data Refresh                    41  High        The following exception occured during datarefresh on http://SiteCollection/sites/abc/document.xlsx
07/12/2017 08:50:55.77  w3wp.exe (0x0C24)                           0x90A4  PowerPivot Service              Data Refresh                    99  High        EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: Call to Excel Services returned an error. ---> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient.Interfaces.ExcelServicesException: We're sorry. We can't open the workbook in the browser because it uses these unsupported features:    • Shapes or other objects ---> Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ExcelServerApiException: We're sorry. We can't open the workbook in the browser because it uses these unsupported features:    • Shapes or other objects     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ApiShared.ExecuteServerSessionMethod(Boolean hasSessionId, String sessionId, CoreServerSessionMethod coreWebMethod, String name, Boolean skipFeatureCheck)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ExcelServiceInternal.OpenWorkbookInternal(String workboo...07/12/2017 08:50:55.77   w3wp.exe (0x0C24)                           0x90A4  PowerPivot Service              Data Refresh                    99  High        EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: Call to Excel Services returned an error. ---> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient.Interfaces.ExcelServicesException: We're sorry. We can't open the workbook in the browser because it uses these unsupported features:    • Shapes or other objects ---> Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ExcelServerApiException: We're sorry. We can't open the workbook in the browser because it uses these unsupported features:    • Shapes or other objects     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ApiShared.ExecuteServerSessionMethod(Boolean hasSessionId, String sessionId, CoreServerSessionMethod coreWebMethod, String name, Boolean skipFeatureCheck)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ExcelServiceInternal.OpenWorkbookInternal(String workboo...
```